# Zero set of a non constant analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Is there any example of a non constant analytic function on { z : |z|<1} , which have infinite zeros in that domain?

Comment: You might contrast your problem and its solution to the discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232039/can-a-non-constant-analytic-function-have-infinitely-many-zeros-on-a-closed-disk , where your open disk is replaced with a closed disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)=\sin (\frac {\pi} {1-z})$ has zeros at $1-\frac  1 n, n=1,2,3,...$.